# Downloading a snapshot from the Wayback Machine?

Tags: archive.org

Is there any way to download a snapshot of an entire website from the Wayback Machine?

I am aware that we can [use wget to recover old website off Wayback Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730491/395857) (e.g. `wget -np -e robots=off --mirror --domains=staticweb.archive.org,web.archive.org http://web.archive.org/web/19970708161549/http://www.slackworks.com/`) but I wonder whether it's possible to do so directly from the Wayback Machine website.

Comment: You can always do the good ol' _File -> Save_

Comment: Sounds a bit tedious if you has to be done for each page of the website :-)

Comment: To get the _whole_ website using `wget`, you will need a few more parameters, e.g `--recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links` — this should include CSS, JS, and, of course, images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to download a snapshot from the Wayback Machine directly as it is not allowed by their [Terms of Use](https://archive.org/about/terms.php).

From their [FAQs](https://archive.org/about/faqs.php):

> **Can people download sites from the Wayback?**
>
> Our terms of use specify that users of the Wayback Machine are not to copy data from the collection.

Comment: That doesn't mean that people don't want to do so and aren't going to do so.

Comment: It may be worth noting that this section was removed from their FAQ and was replaced with this one: https://archive.org/about/faqs.php#26 . Quite simply put, the Wayback Machine doesn't offer copies of their own snapshots. Their language seems to be a bit vague though on whether other tools that download from the wayback are allowed or not.

Answer (score 12):

I've came across the same issue and I've ended up coding a Ruby gem.

To Install:

```
$ gem install wayback_machine_downloader
```

Then, run `wayback_machine_downloader` with the base url of the website you want to retrieve as a parameter (e.g, example.com):

```
$ wayback_machine_downloader http://example.com
```

More information: https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader

Comment: Well done! However, having to install the whole complexity of Ruby just to get this working for a single website is waaaay too much trouble for me... I still prefer the good old `wget` solution.

Comment: They do have a docker image. The bigger problem for me is that their arguments for targeting a specific time range is broken. Which is a problem if you want to download captures for a site that is big and has lots of captures.

Answer (score 1):

There is a service that can download from web archive http://waybackdownloader.com

Comment: Please disclose whether you are affiliated with the site.

Comment: It's one thing helping people write a script to download a website from the Wayback Machine, it's another thing charging for a service that goes against the terms of use.

Answer (score 1):

I made [script](https://gist.github.com/lazanet/872f88c9874e4a7a78fd) for downloading whole site:

```
waybackmachine.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Wayback machine downloader
#TODO: Remove redundancy (download only newest files in given time period - not all of them and then write over them)
############################
clear

#Enter domain without http:// and www.
domain="google.com"
#Set matchType to "prefix" if you have multiple subdomains, or "exact" if you want only one page 
matchType="domain"

#Set datefilter to 1 if you want to download data from specific time period
datefilter=0
from="19700101120001" #yyyyMMddhhmmss
to="20000101120001" #yyyyMMddhhmmss

#Set this to 1 if your page has lots of captured pages with ? in url (experimental)
swapurlarguments=0
usersign='&' #sign to replace ? with

##############################################################
# Do not edit after this point
##############################################################
#Getting snapshot list
full="http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url="
full+="$domain"
full+="&matchType=$matchType"
    if [ $datefilter = 1 ]
        then
            full+="&from=$from&to=$to"
        fi
full+="&output=json&fl=timestamp,original&fastLatest=true&filter=statuscode:200&collapse=original"  #Form request url

wget $full -O rawlist.json #Get snapshot list to file rawlist.json


#Do parsing and downloading stuff
sed 's/\"//g' rawlist.json  > list.json #Remove " from file for easier processing
rm rawlist.json #Remove unnecessary file
i=0; #Set file counter to 0
numoflines=$(cat list.json | wc -l ) #Fill numoflines with number of files to download
while read line;do # For every file
        rawcurrent="${line:1:${#line}-3}" #Remove brackets from JSON line
    IFS=', ' read -a current <<< "$rawcurrent" #Separate timestamp and url
    timestamp="${current[0]}"
    originalurl="${current[1]}"
    waybackurl="http://web.archive.org/web/$timestamp" 
    waybackurl+="id_/$originalurl" #Form request url
    file_path="$domain/"
    sufix="$(echo $originalurl | grep / | cut -d/ -f2- | cut -d/ -f3-)"
     [[ $sufix = "" ]] && file_path+="index.html" || file_path+="$sufix" #Determine local filename
clear
echo " $i out of $numoflines" #Show progress
echo "$file_path"
mkdir -p -- "${file_path%/*}" && touch -- "$file_path" #Make local file for data to be written
    wget -N $waybackurl -O $file_path #Download actual file
    ((i++))
done < list.json

#If user chose, replace ? with usersign
    if [ $swapurlarguments = 1 ]
        then
            cd $domain
            for i in *; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed "s/\?/\$usersign/g"`"; done #Replace ? in filenames with usersign
            find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/\?/\$usersign/g" {} \; #Replace ? in files with usersign
        fi
```

Comment: Better to add important contents of the link in answer .

Comment: I believe that whole script is the answer

Comment: That was a good attempt, but I'm afraid that it doesn't work any longer...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try a wayback machine downloader like http://www.waybackmachinedownloader.com or http://www.waybackmachinedownloads.com

Both of those 2 websites have free demo to scrape few pages from the archive URL to be sure that the script works.

There is other tools but I didn't test them so I can't give a feedback.

Comment: Please add essential contents of the link into answer to make it more useful, as link only answer will become useless if link has changed.